# String split single quotes

Tags: java, regex, string

iam new in regural expressions. I have a String

`String span = "some text, param1:'1123',some text, param2:'3444';"`

Now i want to use split, and get values of param1 and param2.
So i think if i use split by single quotes, i will get array elements with length == 2.
My problem is my split by single quotes doesn't work.
I think i need to put inside single quotes some regex

```
    String[] elements = span.split("''");
    param1 = elements[elements.length-2];
    param2 = elements[elements.length-1];
```

So my output will be:

```
1123
3444
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using regular expression:

```
'(.*?)'
```

`'` is a special character in `Java` so you need to use `Pattern.quote()` to treat it as a literal.

Try:

```
String span = "some text, param1:'1123',some text, param2:'3444';";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("'") + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote("'"));
Matcher m = p.matcher(span);
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

This outputs:

```
1123
3444
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is :

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'(?:[^']|'')+'");
    ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(span);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        values.add(matcher.group());
    }
    nom = values.get(1).replace("'","");
```